# How to execute some script on the ec2 instance from the bitbucket-pipelines.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I've bitbucket repository, bitbucket pipeline there and EC2 instance. EC2 have access to the repository ( can perform pull and docker build/run)

So it seems I only need to upload to EC2 some bash scripts and call it from bitbucket pipeline. How can I call it? Usually ssh connection is used to perform scripts on EC2, is it applicable from bitbucket pipeline? Is it a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two ways to solve this problem, I will leave it up to you.

1. I see you are using AWS, and AWS has a nice service called CodeDeploy. you can use that and create a few deployment scripts and then integrate it with your pipeline. Problem with it is that it is an agent that needs to be installed. so it will consume some resource not much but if u are looking at an agentless design then this solution wont work. you can check the example in the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68933031/8248700
2. You can use something like Python Fabric (its a small gun) or Ansible (its a big canon) to achieve this. it is an agentless design works purely on SSH.

I'm using both the approaches for different scenarios. For AWS I use CodeDeploy and for any other cloud vendor I use Python Fabric. (We can use CodeDeploy on other than AWS but then it comes under on-premise pricing for which it charges for per deployment)

I hope this brings some clarity.