# Permission denied (publickey) AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, ssh-keys

I've added my public SSH key into AWS EC2 instance's `authorized_keys` and I already double checked that the format and values are correct. The problem is I'm unable to login to terminal using following command without a `.pem` file but I can login with the `.pem` file. The issue is why I'm not able to login without a `.pem` file.

Not working with this command:

```bash
sudo ssh ubuntu@publicIPAddress
```

Error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

working with command:

```
sudo ssh -i mypemfile.pem ubuntu@publicIPAddress
```

Answer (score 2):

`ssh` needs to know which key to use to connect to a given host.

In order to drop the `-i` option you need to tell `ssh` where to look for the `.pem` file.

From `man ssh` the `-i`:

> Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read.  You can also specify a public key file to use the corresponding private key
> that is loaded in ssh-agent(1) when the private key file is not present locally.  The default is ~/.ssh/id_rsa ...

Here's what you can do to use `ssh <host name>`:

- Copy your .pem file to the `~/.ssh` folder
- Create a config file with `vim ~/.ssh/config`

Then add the following:

```
Host this_is_your_short_name_for_the_ec2
HostName ec2.full.server.address
User ec2-user (or any other valid user name e.g. ubuntu)
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/<your_key>.pem"
```

If all goes well, you should be able to log in with just:

```bash
ssh my-ec2-host-name
```

Comment: what if I want a 3rd party service to login to my EC2? eg: Bitbucket

Comment: What do you mean? How Bitbucket is supposed to connect to your EC2? As a user? Or do you want to *execute* scripts on the EC2 *from* Bitbucket?

Comment: Yes, I want to execute the script from Bitbucket. I already did that but don't why I'm getting this error at this time.. It's working on other places well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68906490/how-to-execute-some-script-on-the-ec2-instance-from-the-bitbucket-pipelines-yml